# The user input codes I wrote with "JS prototype" do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just learned the concept of JavaScript Prototype. And I wanted to write a user input using Prototype. But the problem came. Only the 'else' section works.

```
$("#but").click(function(){
  var user = $("#username").val()
      pass = $("#password").val();
function control(user,pass){
  this.user = user;
  this.pass = pass;
}

 control.prototype.check = function(){
  if(this.user == "codeblogger" && this.pass == "codeblogger"){
    alert(`WELCOME ${this.user}`);
  }else{
    alert("false")
  }
};

var log = new Object(control.prototype.check);
log();

})
```

Comment: "*`new Object(control.prototype.check);`*" - where did you get that from?

Comment: I was using the "prototype" object as an "object" in a code array I've examined.I thought wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Create an new instance of `control` not `Object`
- Actually define `user` and `pass` before you try to read them

Thus

```
var log = new control(user, pass);
log.check();
```

As an aside, convention dictates that constructor functions are named starting with a capital letter, so it should be `Control`, not `control`.